# Finding the number of triads.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $( X, Y, Z )$ be the subsets of the set $ U $ on $ n$ elements satisfying the conditions:
\begin{align*}
1. \quad X &\subseteq (X \cap Z) \cup Y' \\
2. \quad Y &\subseteq (Z \cap X) \cup Z' \\
3. \quad Z &\subseteq (X \cap Y) \cup X' 
\end{align*}
Find the number of such triads $ (X, Y, Z) $.

I have approached the problem like this:
For each element $u$ in $U$, it has $5$ choices:

1. $u $ can be in $X$ but not $Y$ or $Z$ (which is only possible if $u$ is in $Y'$).
2. $u$ can be in $ Y $ but not $ X $ or $ Z $ (which is only possible if $u$ is in $ Z' $).
3. $u$ can be in $ Z $ but not $ X $ or $ Y $ (which is only possible if $u$ is in $ X' $).
4. $u$ can be in $ X, Y, Z $ (which is only possible if $u$ is in $ X \cap Y \cap Z $).
5. $u$ can be in none of $ X, Y, Z $ (which is always possible).

So it's $5^n$.

Comment: I wanted to move about this problem in inclusion-exclusion way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you mistype the bulletin 1.?

Comment: What is $X'$? The complement of $X$ in $U$, i.e $X^\complement$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $3$ subsets $X, Y, Z$ delimit by their intersections and complements $2^3 = 8$ subsets. For simplicity, we'll call them $XYZ, XY, YZ, ZX, X, Y, Z, 0$, where $XY$ means $X \cap Y \cap Z^\complement$, etc., and $0$ is $X^\complement \cap Y^\complement \cap Z^\complement$.

The first condition is equivalent to: $XY$ is empty.
Similarly, the two other conditions are equivalent to: $YZ$ and $ZX$ are empty.

Each element of $U$ can be put into one of the $5$ remaining subsets: $XYZ, X, Y, Z, 0$. So, yes, there are $5^n$ possibilities for $(X,Y,Z)$.